# Java Directory Listing problem

Tags: java, directory, jlist

I want to list all the folders of the current directory but there are two problems. Everytime i run this program, the list shows all the files of the last folder inside the directory and the filter does not work.

Can you please help me?

```
public void foldersPanel()
{

    JPanel folderScreen = new JPanel();
    folderScreen.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    direFilter = new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File file, String string)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    File directory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles(direFilter);
    String[] allFiles = directory.list();

    if (directory.isDirectory())
    {
        int x = 1;

        for (int i =0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++)  // displays all the files
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
            {
                folderList = new JList(listOfFiles[i].list(direFilter));
                System.out.println(x +") Directory = " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                x++;
                folderList.setSelectedIndex(1);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("is file");
            }
            folderScreen.add(new JScrollPane(folderList));

        }

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is a file, not a directory, so we will move to the parent folder");
        directory = directory.getParentFile();
        updateLabels();
        System.out.println("The new directory is : " +directory.toString());
    }
}
```

`code`

Comment: What specific error are you getting?  What do you mean by the "last folder in the directory".  Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: inside the current directory are 3 folders, folder 1, folder 2 and folder 3. Everytime i run this code the location of the directory is current directory/folder3

Answer (score 0):

Your method isn't recursive.  A directory is a tree; you want to recursively call a method that adds the list of files to an overall list if it's a directory, or simply add the file if it's a file.  Keep accumulating all the lists and you'll have every file under the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `FilenameFilter.accept` is the containing directory. Effectively, your test will always return `true`.

[EDIT]

More specifically, I think you really want your test to be:

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
    return new File(dir, fileName).isDirectory();
}
```

Comment: Oh, and maybe you should think about using `FileFilter` instead. Probably better matches your need.